# Why does \iow_shipout: introduce typeset whitespace (where \iow_now: does not)?

Tags: spacing, expl3, auxiliary-files

For my resume, I have an environment that
  lays out information in two minipages—one
  for position/education data,
  one for the environment contents.
The class I wrote also produces plain text output (mostly for giggles at this point):

```
\cs_new:Nn \resume_maybe_write:n {
  \tl_if_empty:NF \g_resume_options_output_text_file_tl {
    \iow_now:Nx \g_resume_output_text_iow { #1 }
  }
}
```

and it is this is actually what is causing the spacing issue visible here:

[image: output]

You'll notice that the addition of `\hrule` on the top and bottom of the second `minipage` environment fixes the issue.  I'm not sure why—`texdef hrule` seems to show it's a primitive (!?).

The full source is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/vermiculus/resume-cv/blob/2f6ab7a4edc383e6e5bfdc1f99491b68d83f05a9/bettercv.position.tex#L58)
  (where the writing occurs [here][github-ioq]),
  but I stress that the change that *completely* fixed the issue was [this one](https://github.com/vermiculus/resume-cv/commit/2f6ab7a4edc383e6e5bfdc1f99491b68d83f05a9#commitcomment-5174294).

---

My actual problem is fixed, but I'm *very* curious: what could be causing this?
Should this be considered a bug in `l3file`, or is it expected behavior?
If the latter, why is it so?

Comment: translating back into english, `\immediate\write{jjj}` does not make a node, so it is very unlikely tp affect spacing of anything, it just writes to the specified output stream. `\write{..}` does make a node that migrates to the main vertical list there and typically sits there messing up spacing until you get to shipout. It's really quite hard to stop whatsit nodes messing up spacing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah… I should have noticed these were just wrappers around `\write` and `\immediate\write`… Should I edit accordingly?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you turn your comment into an answer?  Essentially, the answer is that it's "TeX's fault" :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Translating back into TeX primitive names:

`\immediate\write...{...}` does not make a node, so it is very unlikely to affect spacing of anything, it just writes to the specified output stream.

`\write...{..}` does make a node that sits there messing up spacing until you output a page with `\shipout`.

It's really quite hard to stop *whatsit* nodes messing up spacing. You see the same with colour support. Especially having such nodes in a vertical list is problematic, and in general avoiding putting them in a vertical list is hard.

Comment: For completeness, I want to mention that it is possible to make some constructions work despite a /whatsit/ node.  David Kastrup has a BachoTeX pearl defining [a corrected version `\vtop`](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2008p/david-kastrup/bachotex2008-david-kastrup-pearl1.pdf) (which, to be honest, I don't understand).